# How can I solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}}dx$ using $2\tan\theta$ as substitution for x?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, substitution

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}}dx$$

*-from the book Advanced Problems in Mathematics by Vikas Gupta*

So I tried to solve this integral by substituting $x=2\tan\theta$ so that we get the upper limit as ${\frac{\pi}{2}}$ in addition to the ability to use the formula $\log(ab)=\log a + \log b$ in the numerator. But after few manipulations I ended up with this [image: my workout]

Could you kindly advise on how to proceed further as I got $\log(\infty)$ when I used integration by parts. Also if there is a cleverer way to do this, I would love to know it!

Comment: Try $x=10^k$, maybe?

Comment: Wait, do you mean I should use the Feyman integral technique after doing that? I'm just in high school so I really don't know the method well but have seen it in yt

Comment: Are you obliged to use this substitution ?

Comment: Not really. But I felt this would work the best here. But please feel free to help me using any other substitution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2750316/1129056

Comment: More generally, one can [obtain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634091/generalisation-of-an-already-generalised-integral?noredirect=1) from methods involving the beta function or contour integration, for example, that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{x^n+a^n}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{n} a^{s-n}\csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{n}\right)$$ So take $n=2, a=2$ and proceed to differentiate with respect to $s$, then take $s\to 1$.

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman, I only suggested the substitution. I don't even know whether it would work or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write,
$$I=\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d} x$$

Notice
\begin{eqnarray}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d} x + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d} x \\
&= G + H
\end{eqnarray}
Now
\begin{eqnarray}
G &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d} x \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+1}\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x - \ln 2+ \ln 2}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+1}\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x - \ln 2}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+1}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\ln 2}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+1}\mathrm{d}x \\
&= G_1 + G_2
\end{eqnarray}

Further
\begin{eqnarray}
G_1 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x/2)dx}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+1}
\end{eqnarray}

Let $x/2 = y$ thus
\begin{eqnarray}
G_1 &= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{y^2+1}\mathrm{d}y \\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln u}{u^2+1}\mathrm{d}u
\end{eqnarray}
Where the last step was achieved by writing $u=1/y$.

Meanwhile back at the ranch,
\begin{eqnarray}
G_2 &= \frac{\ln 2}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u \\
&=  \frac{\ln 2}{2} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Since I have many dummy variables, the result for $G_1 = -H$ and thus the final answer is $G_2$ above for the initial $I$. Hence

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d} x = \frac{\ln 2}{2} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in an answer using contours, here it is.

Let $f(z)=\ln^2(z)/(z^2+4)$. I will use the branch of the logarithm with the cut along the positive real axis, i.e, $0<\arg (z)<2\pi$, and a keyhole contour $\mathcal{C}$ surrounding $[0,+\infty)$ in a counter-clockwise sense. The contributions from the big outer cirlce and small inner circle vanish so we have from the definition of a complex logarithm $\ln(z)=\ln{|z|}+i\arg(z)$,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\ln^2(z)}{z^2+4}\ dz&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2+4}\ dx+\int_{+\infty}^0\frac{(\ln(x)+2\pi i)^2}{x^2+4}\ dx \\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{4\pi^2-2\pi i\ln(x)}{x^2+4}\ dx 
\end{align*}$$
Write $I$ for the integral above. Notice that the integral we are looking for is the imaginary part of $I$ multiplied by a factor of $-1/2\pi$.
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\ dx=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\text{Im}(I)$$

Now, the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) implies,
$$\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\ln^2(z)}{z^2+4}\ dz=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f,2i)+\text{Res}(f,-2i)\right]$$
and we can compute the residues by hand.
At $z=2i$ there is a simple pole,
$$\text{Res}(f,2i)=\lim_{z\to2i}(z-2i)f(z)=\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{8}+\frac{\pi^2-16\ln^2(2)}{64}i$$
and at $z=-2i$ the pole is simple too.
$$\text{Res}(f,-2i)=\lim_{z\to-2i}(z+2i)f(z)=-\frac{3\pi\ln(2)}{8}+\frac{16\ln^2(2)-9\pi^2}{64}i$$
Adding these contributions,
$$I=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\ln^2(z)}{z^2+4}\ dz=2\pi i\left(-\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}i\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{4}-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{2}i$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\ dx&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\text{Im}\left(\frac{\pi^3}{4}-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{2}i\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(-\frac{\pi^2\ln(2)}{2}\right) \\
&=\frac{\pi }{4}\ln(2).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks bob, I havnt learnt contours yet, but one day ill revisit this answer after learning them. And thank you so much for letting me know there is a way like this:)

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman No problem :)